# Simple fadeOut() working erratically as ajax callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxform

This is driving me mad!

I can't figure out why the `fadeOut()` function is not working here. I'm sure it's going to be something annoyingly simple, but I just can't see it. When the trigger button is clicked, the first `fadeOut()` works fine - `#page3` fades out as expected and `#holdingpage` fades in. However, once the ajax call is completed the `#holdingPage` div does NOT fade out, but the `#thanksPage` div DOES fade in, so I'm left with the contents of both the `#holdingPage` div AND the `#thanksPage` div. The ajax call itself is working fine - the form is submitted and data written to the database via the php script.

Can anyone help?!

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="page3" class="surveyDivs">
...blah...blah...blah...
</div>

<div id="holdingPage" class="surveyDivs" style="display: none;">
  <div class="loadingDiv">
    <img class="loadingImage" src="../css/ajax-loader.gif" />
  </div>
</div>

<div id="thanksPage" class="surveyDivs" style="display: none;">
...blah...blah...blah...
</div>
```

Jquery

```
docu.on('click', "#finishSurveyButton", function(){
  $('#page3').fadeOut(function(){
  $('#holdingPage').fadeIn();
  });
  $("#inductSurvForm").ajaxForm({
    success: function(data){
      $('#holdingPage').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#thanksPage').fadeIn();  
      });

      }
    }).submit();    
  });
```

Comment: what is this docu? in jquery

Comment: Just `$(document)` wrapped in a variable

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle

Comment: try writing the ajax function fully in the animation complete of $('#page3').fadeOut();
I guess the sequence goes haywire here because the ajax has to be called once the page has fadedin and might be the ajax calls happening faster than the fadeIn

Comment: docu.on('click', "#finishSurveyButton", function(){
  $('#page3').fadeOut(function(){
  $('#holdingPage').fadeIn();
$("#inductSurvForm").ajaxForm({
    success: function(data){
      $('#holdingPage').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#thanksPage').fadeIn();  
      });

      }
    }).submit();    
  });

  
  });

Comment: are you sure submit callback is invoked?

Comment: @sss - can you proceed your answer in answer Draft that should be only users should view your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing the ajax function fully in the animation complete of $('#page3').fadeOut(); I guess the sequence goes haywire here because the ajax has to be called once the page has fadedin and might be the ajax calls happening faster than the fadeIn

```
docu.on('click', "#finishSurveyButton", function(){
  $('#page3').fadeOut(function(){
  $('#holdingPage').fadeIn();
  });
  $("#inductSurvForm").ajaxForm({
    success: function(data){
      $('#holdingPage').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#thanksPage').fadeIn();  
      });

      }
    }).submit();    
  });
```